# Что лучше, возвращать null, или пустую коллекцию?

Tags: c#, коллекции

Если возвращаемый тип — коллекция, что лучше: возвращать `null` или пустую коллекцию? Есть ли общепринятая практика?

Аналогичный вопрос на en.SO:  [Is it better to return null or empty collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969993/1988244)

Comment: Простите, а вы серьезно задаете этот вопрос или расширяете базу ruSO/зарабатываете знак?

Comment: Это хороший вопрос, и для меня важно, чтобы другие пользователи получили хороший ответ, если у них такой же вопрос.

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy раз уж это дословный перевод [чужого вопроса Is it better to return null or empty collection? с enSO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1969993/1988244) - может быть стоит добавить ссылку на оригинал?

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. Неужели в мире уже кто-то этот вопрос задавал, да еще и на другом языке?

Comment: @GeorgePolevoy: вы ведь даже шутку про проколотые шины перевели. Зачем скрывать факт перевода? Переводы это хорошо, а вот не указывать авторство — плохо.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969993/

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Вопрос здесь в семантике.

На запрос «дайте мне список всех пользователей» пустая коллекция имеет очевидный смысл: «окей, вот вам список всех пользователей, их ровно 0 штук».

С другой стороны, возвращённый `null` может означать что угодно: «я не знаю, сколько пользователей», «количество пользователей ещё не подсчитано», «текущая база данных вообще не имеет понятия *пользователь*», что угодно.

Смысл пустой коллекции всегда ясен, смысл `null` не определён.

Статья по теме: *Eric Lippert, [Null Is Not Empty](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/null-is-not-empty)*.

Answer (score 26):

Лучше возвращать пустые коллекции - так вы избавите пользователя от необходимости писать утомительный код проверок на null и, соответственно, избавите его от энного количества `NullReferenceException`, если он таковой код написать забыл. Хорошим примером могут быть случаи, когда коллекции задействованы в цепочках методов вида

```
var res = FirstMethod().SecondMethod().ThirdMethod();
```

и в случае, если коллекция равна `null`, вся цепочка может быть обрушена исключением, тогда как проверки на `null` превратят этот лаконичный и довольно элегантный синтаксис в кашу из вложенных `if`-ов.  Для коллекций это можно считать общепринятой практикой.

Кстати, обратите внимание, что в LINQ именно так и делается. Например, следующий код вполне нормально работает без выбрасывания исключений, хотя очевидно, что ни один из элементов коллекции не удовлетворяет условию лямбды в `Where`:

```
var res2 = new[] { 1, 2, 3 }.Where(x => x > 10).Select(x => x);
```

Answer (score 7):

Пустую коллекцию легче использовать и код получается менее подвержен ошибкам.
Но я **не** согласен с мнением, что нужно **всегда** возвращать пустую коллекцию.
Создание любого объекта означает потребление ресурсов: памяти и процессора. Рано или поздно этот объект (коллекция) будет удалён - это работа сборщика мусора, то есть опять потребление ресурсов.

В случае, если нужна производительность, придётся отказаться от создания ненужных объектов (пустых коллекций). В частности, разрабочики Resharper в своих докладах много рассказывали о memory traffic и как они с ним боролись. В частности, там используются хитрые коллекции, в которых несколько значений хранятся в полях класса. И лишь когда их становится много - выделяется память под полноценную коллекцию в куче.

Comment: `Enumerable.Empty` позволяет не расходовать память на создание "пустых коллекций".

Comment: @PashaPash - `Enumerable.Empty` - хороший выход. Однако, там всё равно создаётся экземпляр массива нулевого размера (заглянул сейчас в [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/Enumerable.cs,81187dce3836739d)) и кэшируется.

Comment: да, я скорее хотел дополнить ответ, чем возразить - просто если использовать пустые коллекции - то стоит использовать именно Empty, а не создавать каждый раз `new List<T>()`

Comment: Но ведь он создаётся один раз и не уничтожается. А несколько байт памяти не жалко.

Comment: Преждевременная оптимизация — источник всех бед. Если есть проблема с памятью, вы должны провести профилирование, найти bottleneck, тот самый 1%, в котором нужно пожертвовать идеологической верностью кода ради производительности. Но ухудшать _остальной_ код всё равно не имеет смысла. Насчёт «всегда», мне кажется, никто и не говорит.

Comment: _"Создание любого объекта означает потребление ресурсов"_ -- на практике процессоры (не в серверах) в основном загружены на 10-20%

Answer (score 4):

Всегда когда есть некостыльная альтернатива возвращению `null`, нужно пользоваться этой альтернативой. Меньше проблем потом будет.
Так что конечно лучше возвращать пустую коллекцию.

Comment: Объясните почему, аргументируйте. В текущем виде ответ звучит "делайте А потому что А".

Comment: Потому что null это зло и простеший способ порождения ошибок + создает лишние проверки в коде. В первую очередь это к высокоуровневым языкам относится, по которым и задан вопрос. Вместо того чтобы делать алгоритмы, ты вставляешь в начало каждого метода проверки на null, дабы ничего не упало, нагромождаешь код.
Немного истории:
[раз](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullable_type),
[два](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tony_Hoare),
[три](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/Null-References-The-Billion-Dollar-Mistake-Tony-Hoare)

Comment: "Потому что null это зло" - аргументный аргумент )

Answer (score 3):

Если не хотите ловить исключение типа, связанное с тем, что значение отсутсвует - то лучше пустую коллекцию. А вообще нужно исходить из поставленной задачи. Если метод должен возвращать список каких-то элементов, то в случае отсутствия элементов - должен быть возвращен пустой список. Значение **null** должно возвращаться в особых случаях, когда это заранее оговорено и поставлена задача.

Answer (score 2):

Лучше возвращать пустую коллекцию.

Совершенно не хочется писать код вроде этого:

```
if (container.ItemsProperty != null)
{
    foreach (var item in container.ItemsProperty)
        // Ужас!
}
```

Лучше возвратите пустую коллекцию коллекцию/IEnumerable, это общепринятая практика.

Это поможет избежать вышеупомянутого безумия, и так ваши коллеги и пользователи вашего класса не проколят шины вашего автомобиля.

Если говорить о свойствах, присвойте и забудьте:

```
public IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; private set; }
public Container() { Items = Enumerable.Empty<Item>(); }
```

Если это метод - то вернуть пустую коллекцию легко:

```
public IEnumerable<Song> GetListOfMyFavoriteEmoSongs()
{
    return Enumerable.Empty<Song>();
}
```

`Enumerable.Empty<T>()` немного эффективнее чем, например, создавать новый пустой массив, или делать `yeild break`.

---

Это перевод ответа с en.SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1970001/2790048