# Как проверить на пустоту Dictionary<Type1 value1, Type2 value2> в C#

Tags: c#, null, словари

Каким образом можно проверить словарь на пустоту, если заранее не известно названий ключей. Есть ли какая-нибудь функция вроде **IsNullOrEmpty()**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Посмотреть количество элементов в словаре можно при помощи свойства Count:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
var cnt = dict.Count;
```

Проверить наличие ключа в словаре можно так:

```
if (dict.ContainsKey("key1"))
{
    // ... ключ есть в словаре
}
```

Проверить и получить значение по ключу за одну операцию:

```
string str;
if (dict.TryGetValue("key1", out str))
{
    // ... ключ есть в словаре
}
```

**UPDATE**

Можно воспользоваться методом расширения:

```
if (dict.IsNullOrEmpty())
{
    // ... словарь пустой
}

static class DictionaryExtentions
{
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dict)
    {
        return dict == null || dict.Count == 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Спасибо за подробный ответ! А если **dict = null**? Метод Count() не выбросит exception в этом случае?

Comment: Да, выбросит exception. Нужна проверка. Но и в методе Any будет exception. В моем примере, кстати, экземпляр создан.

Comment: А есть ли какой-то "безопасный" способ проверки, без exception?

Comment: Добавил в ответ

Comment: @neo безопасный способ - всегда использовать пустые коллекции вместо null. это семантически разные вещи: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/471212/

Answer (score 3):

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` реализует интерфейс `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`, что делает применимыми к нему стандартные расширения для `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
using System.Linq;

....

if (dictionary.Any())
{
    // не пустой!
}
```

null и пустая коллекция - семантически разные вещи. Их нельзя смешивать в коде. То, что приходится делать проверки и на null, и на пустоту - это признак проблемы в дизайне, и решать ее стоит использованием пустых коллекций вместо null.

Вот хороший вопрос на эту тему: [Что лучше, возвращать null, или пустую коллекцию?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/471212/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-null-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E)

Comment: если `dictionary == null` - это упадет, если случай с _null_ не рассматривается, то, возможно, лишний тег _null_ на вопросе

Comment: @Grundy скорее всего рассматривается. и топикастеру стоит почитать http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/471212/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-null-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E