# чтение и удаление текстовых файлов

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь написать программу, которая проверяет текстовые файлы, и, если они содержат определенную последовательность символов, удаляет их. Проблема в том, что при удалении выскакиевает ошибка "процесс не может получить доступ к файлу, т.к этот файл используется другим процессом" При этом сам файл я даже не открывал.

Вот код:

```
try
{
    var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(
                                     @"c:\test\", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                from line in File.ReadLines(file)
                where line.Contains("NoOneLivesForever")
                select ne
                {
                    File = file,
                    Line = line
                };

    foreach (var f in files)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", f.File, f.Line);
        System.IO.File.Delete(f.File);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("{0} files found.", files.Count().ToString());
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException UAEx)
{
    Console.WriteLine(UAEx.Message);
}
catch (PathTooLongException PathEx)
{
    Console.WriteLine(PathEx.Message);
}
```

Comment: Как это вы файл не открывали, но получили его содержимое?

Comment: Вы бы хоть постеснялись того, что кладёте логику программы в OnClick, и не показывали это, стыдно же. Убрал лишний код.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File.ReadLines` надо заменить на `File.ReadAllLines`.
Иначе `File.Delete` вызывается когда файл открыт во время `File.ReadLines`.

Comment: Плохой совет. Вы при этом заставляете грузить весь файл в память, то есть разменяли одну проблему на другую.

Comment: @VladD _"Вы при этом заставляете грузить весь файл в память"_ -- не заставляю. Мы не знаем размер файла. и обратите внимание, что в коде указан `select new {File=file, Line=line}`

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines` грузит в память по-любому весь файл же, не смотря на Select.

Comment: загружается и закрывается, поэтому в момент вызова Delete не происходит ошибка. доступа. Но если итератор обращается к ReadLines, то файл будет открыт до завершения работы итератора.

Comment: А теперь представьте себе, что в файле 3 гигабайта строк. Зачем грузить его весь в память, если вам нужно только проверить наличие одной строки?

Comment: а если не 3 Gb, а 30 Kb -- мы же не знаем. и бывает, что небольшие файлы лучше быстро прочесть целиком, закрыть его и дальше для каждой строки делать что-то относительно сложное/долгое. А если в такой ситуации использовать ReadLines, то файл будет открыт до завершения работы итератора.

Comment: Ну так и с этим надо бороться, со слишком длинной жизнью итератора. И не жертвовать для этого памятью. Вы ж программист! :)

Comment: @VladD _"так и с этим надо бороться"_ -- по этому поводу есть ответ -- [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/471212/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d1%88%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-null-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e/471242#comment533384_471239) -- сразу в первом предложении.

Answer (score 0):

Вы делаете что-то лишнее. Делайте просто:

```
var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(
                                 path, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            where File.ReadLines(file).Contains("NoOneLivesForever")
            select file;

foreach (var f in files)
    File.Delete(f);
```

---

Вот код с неизменённой по отношению к вопросу семантикой:

```
var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(
                                 path, "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            let lines = (from line in File.ReadLines(file)
                         where line.Contains("NoOneLivesForever")
                         select line).ToList()
            where lines.Count > 0
            select new { File = file, Lines = lines };

foreach (var f in files)
{
    foreach (var l in f.Lines)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", f.File, l);
    File.Delete(f.File);
}
```

Comment: в вопросе: перед удалением файла, строки из него выводятся на Console.

Comment: @Stack: Выводится только `NoOneLivesForever`, а не весь файл.

Comment: дело не в том, что выводится, а в том, что файл остается открытым пока работает итератор, который использует ReadLines. поэтому Delete вызовет ошибку доступа к файлу.

Comment: Ну да. У меня-то в решении файл закрывается сразу, проблем нет. В чём ваша претензия? В том, что мой код не сможет вывести эту строчку? Может: `foreach (var f in files) Console.WriteLine("{0}\tNoOneLivesForever", f);`.

Comment: если код из вопроса: `select new { File=file,Line=line};` и `Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", f.File, f.Line);` копировать в ваш код, то Delete работает без ошибок?

Comment: @Stack: Мой код вообще не запоминает line, потому что это константа `"NoOneLivesForever"`, её нет смысла запоминать.

Comment: понятно. но в вопросе .Contains - т.е. строки проверяются, на наличие NoOneLivesForever. Строки могут быть длинными, содержать например, номера телефонов, и в итераторе, например, надо позвонить на указанный в строке номер, дождатья ответ и т.д. Все это время файл будет открыт. В некоторых случаях это нежелательно.

Comment: @Stack: Ну боже ж мой. Обновил ответ.