# Что необходимо возвращать из функции: null или пустой объект?

Tags: c#, .net, архитектура, проектирование

Что является *лучшей практикой* при возвращении данных из функции. Лучше возвратить `null` или пустой объект? И почему необходимо использовать один вариант по сравнению с другим.

Рассмотрим следующий вариант:

```
public UserEntity GetUserById(Guid userId)
{
     //Здесь код доступа к базе данных...

     //Проверяем вернувшиеся данные и возвращаем null если ничего не найдено
     if (!DataExists)
        return null; 
        //Или же я должен вернуть пустой объект?
        //return new UserEntity();  
     else
        return existingUserEntity;
}
```

[Перевод](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1626597/5610621)

Comment: @andreycha почему тег c# убрали? в тексте вопроса код на c#.

Comment: @Stack потому что вопрос language agnostic и подходит для любого языка, допускающего null ссылки. И к .NET тоже не имеет никакого отношения. Вы ко мне теперь во всех вопросах будете цепляться? :)

Comment: Тэг [tag:архитектура], на мой взгляд, слишком громкий для такого вопроса. Пожалуй, нам бы не помешал тэг [tag:лучшие-практики].

Comment: @andreycha _"потому что вопрос language agnostic"_ -- ну так у многих вопросов, где есть тег c# можно этот тег, или убрать вообще, или добавить typescript. потому что синтаксис похож) но это неправильно. если ошиблись, можно исправить, что уже и сделали. никто лично к вам не цепляется. у меня была открыта страница - теги были и исчезли. если бы это сделал кто-то другой, то я бы точно также написал коммент.

Comment: @andreycha У нас метка "language-agnostic" называется "любой-язык", но проблема в том, что в этом вопросе рассматривается конкретный язык конкретной версии на конкретной платформе. В других языках — другие возможности, практики и традиции. Мой ответ совершенно непригоден для языков, где используются опциональный тип и паттерн-матчинг.

Comment: Похожий по тематике вопрос [Что лучше, возвращать null, или пустую коллекцию?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/471212/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-null-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E?rq=1)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Выбор между `null` и null-объектом зависит от того, как метод будет использоваться.

## Примеры

#### Получение коллекции пользователей

```
ICollection<User> GetAllUsers();
```

Как этот метод будет использоваться? Скорее всего, примерно так:

```
foreach (User user in userService.GetAllUsers()) {
    // Обработка или отображение конкретного юзера
}
```

Возвращение пустой коллекции в этом случае нам позволит сэкономить на одном `if` (`foreach` не умеет игнорировать `null`). Нам неважно, были какие-то элементы в коллекции или нет, логика вызывающего метода от этого обычно не зависит. Если же зависит, то мы всегда можем воспользоваться свойством `Count`.

#### Получение одного пользователя

```
User GetUser(int id);
```

Как этот метод будет использоваться? Скорее всего, примерно так:

```
User user = userService.GetUser(id);
if (user == null) {
    // Всё плохо, обработать ошибку
}
else {
    // Обработать или отобразить пользователя
}
```

В этом случае разумно вернуть `null`, потому что наличие и отсутствие результата предполагает различное поведение вызывающего кода.

Чего точно не следует делать — это возвращать `new User()`: это не позволит нормально проверить, существует запрошенный пользователь или нет. Если уж делать null-объекты, то они по возможности должны быть в единственном экземпляре и неизменяемы.

#### Получение текущего пользователя

```
User GetCurrentUser();
```

Как этот метод будет использоваться? Скорее всего, примерно так:

```
User currentUser = userService.GetCurrentUser();
Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1})", currentUser.Name, currentUser.Level);
```

В этом случае обработка пользователя обычно не зависит от наличия или отсутствия реального пользователя, поэтому можно вернуть объект "пользователь-гость". В случае, если проверка требуется, то можно реализовать свойство вроде `User.IsRegistered` или `User.AccessLevel`.

## Планы на будущее

В C# 7 планируется добавить разделение между nullable и non-nullable для reference-типов (в дополнение к value-типам). Тогда методы выше будут выглядеть так:

```
ICollection<User> GetAllUsers();
User? GetUser(int id); // Обратите внимание на знак вопроса
User GetCurrentUser();
```

Если вызвать метод `GetUser` и не проверить на значение `null`, то компилятор выдаст предупреждение.

## ReSharper

Если у вас есть R#, то вы можете добавить аннотации уже сейчас:

```
[NotNull, ItemNotNull]
ICollection<User> GetAllUsers();
[CanBeNull]
User GetUser(int id);
[NotNull]
User GetCurrentUser();
```

Эти аннотации позволят анализатору R# явно разделять, что может быть `null`, а что не может, и за счёт этого предупреждать пользователя о потенциальных ошибках.

Answer (score 9):

Если вы под пустым объектом понимаете [Null Object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern), я бы практически никогда не рекомендовал его использовать. Проблема в том, что это позволяет подавить ошибку вместо того, чтобы проверить её. Этот паттерн по сути не особенно отличается от возвращения кода ошибки, только код ошибки при этом совмещён с возвращаемым объектом.

В случае возвращения `null` код, который по ошибке не проверяет это, немедленно упадёт в первом же тесте. Если же возвращать искусственный «пустой объект», код, который не проверяет его, будет считать, что он правильно работает, и вы никогда не найдёте ошибку.

У метода должен быть *контракт*: имеет ли право возвращаемый объект «отсутствовать» или нет. Для случая, когда отсутствие возвращаемого объекта есть нормальный, ожидаемый случай, нужно возвращать `null`. Для случая, когда отсутствие возвращаемого объекта означает по сути ошибку, нужно выбросить исключение.

Возврат коллекции из метода работает по сути так же. Если у вас метод отработал нормально, и полученная коллекция оказалась пустой (и это не является ошибкой), вы обычным образом возвращаете коллекцию, состоящую из 0 элементов, это нормальный случай, успешное выполнение функции. Если у вас в результате ошибки результата нет, и это ожидаемый случай, то имеет смысл вернуть `null`. Если у вас в результате ошибки результата нет, и этот случай в принципе не является ожидаемым, то стоит выбросить исключение.

Comment: >Для случая, когда отсутствие возвращаемого объекта означает по сути ошибку, нужно выбросить исключение.

Примеры в студию.

Comment: @hellboy: Получение элемента из массива по неверному индексу устроит?

Answer (score 8):

Возвращение `null` мне кажется лучшей идеей для случаев  когда данные недоступны

Возвращение пустого объекта предполагает что данные были возвращены, в то время как возврат `null` ясно дает понять что ничего возвращено не было.

Кроме того, возврат `null` может привести к возникновению `NullReferenceException` при попытке доступа к членам объекта, что может быть полезно для выявления ошибочного кода. Доступ же к членам пустого объекта не приведет к возникновению ошибки и данная ошибка долго может оставаться нераскрытой.

[Перевод](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1626620/5610621)

Answer (score 5):

> возвратить null или пустой объект?

Для reference-типов обычно возвращают null, а для value-типов возвращают 'пустой объект' Empty (определен во многих структурах в .NET Framework).

Надо стараться не возвращать null, т.к. это является причиной большого количества багов. Tony Hoare (добавил null в algol в 1965) в 2009 году сказал, что null reference
-- The Billion Dollar Mistake (ошибка на миллиард долларов).

Например, если метод не может вернуть запрошенный объект, то вместо возврата null, можно использовать принцип [Fail Fast](http://habrahabr.ru/post/218325/). Или надо переопределить метод как Try*, например, int.TryParse.

Answer (score 1):

Частично эту проблему можно решить с помощью монады Maybe, т.е. возвращать что-то вроде:

```
Maybe<User> GetUser(int id);
```

Или же монада With:

```
string name = rep.GetUser(-1).With(u => u.Name);
```

Можно использовать библиотеки из nuget (искать по monads).
Хотя такой подход накладывает обязательства на его поддержку во всей модели.
Ссылки по теме:

- http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2014/06/void-safety-in-c.html - Борьба с "нулевыми" ссылками в C#
- http://devtalk.net/2010/09/12/chained-null-checks-and-the-maybe-monad/ - Chained null checks and the Maybe monad