# Насколько корректно возвращать null из метода?

Tags: c#

Давно мучает один вопрос, пишу бота на С# и в некоторых методах возвращаю null насколько это корректно?
Пример

```
    public async Task<Message> CommandPlaceAnOrderAsync(TelegramBotClient botClient, int userId, int messageId, string callbackQueryId, string inputCommand)
    {
        CommandsDataBaseShop dataBase = new CommandsDataBaseShop();
        await dataBase.AddOrUpdateLastCommandAsync(userId, "PlaceAnOrder");
        int id = int.Parse(InputCommandParsing(inputCommand)[1]);
        if (await dataBase.CheckingForProductStockAsync(id))
        {
            await botClient.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(callbackQueryId, " Выберите способ доставки");
            return await botClient.EditMessageReplyMarkupAsync(userId, messageId, replyMarkup: new Keyboard().DeliveryMethodKeyboard(id));//Возвращает сообщение
        }
        else
        {
            await botClient.AnswerCallbackQueryAsync(callbackQueryId, "‍♀️ Извините, но товар закончился"); // Метод ничего не возвращает.
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Зависит от логики вашего метода. Допустим есть метод `GetUser(...)`, который должен вернуть пользователя из базы, вот он вам отдал `NULL`, что это означает? Наверно то, что пользователя нету, ок, а как быть если нам надо конкретно знать из за чего его там нету? Может наши параметры имеют неверное значение, может мы передаем туда пустые параметры, может нету соединения с базой, ведь мы можем во всех этих случаях вернуть `NULL`, а это означает, что конечную проблему мы скрыли. Ну вот дальше думайте, подходит ли под вашу задачу `NULL`. Также гляньте [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/471212).

Comment: Как по мне, выглядит нормально. Можете создать статическое свойство `Message.Empty` и возвращаеть его вместо `null`, но логика от этого не поменяется.

Comment: Я сигнатуру метода поменял и сделал метод без возвращающего значение просто Task пусть, будет так. Надеюсь, так можно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

null нужно возвращать только на методах очень низкого уровня.

Когда речь идет методах высокого уровня, сервисах, контроллах и т.п., то лучше использовать осознанный класс ответа. Что-то вроде:

```
public class ServiceResult<T>{
   public bool IsValid { get;set; }
   public string Message { get;set; }
   public T Result { get;set; }
}
```